# How to Insert DataGridViewComboBoxCell in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I want to insert a combobox for each row in datagrid, but when I tried to send a combobox for specific cell it doesn't work

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dtRecord.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        int idRecord = Convert.ToInt32(dtRecord.Rows[i]["idRecord"].ToString());

        DataTable dtDetalleRecordPorId = new DataTable();
        dtDetalleRecordPorId = cnEvalua.CNListaDetalleRecord(idRecord);

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell
        {
            DataSource = dtDetalleRecordPorId,
            ValueMember = dtDetalleRecordPorId.Columns["idDetalleRecord"].ToString(),
            DisplayMember = dtDetalleRecordPorId.Columns["cValor"].ToString(),
            ReadOnly = false
        };

        dtgRecord.Rows[i].Cells["cValor"] = cmb;
    }
```

When I debug and check datasource value of datagrid is empty. How can I insert that combobox?

My datagrid take data from this part:

```
    dtRecord = cnEvalua.CNListaRecord();
    dtgRecord.DataSource = dtRecord;
```

When I check datasource of gridview the column `cValor` is empty but other columns have data.

Comment: You should add `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to the grid.

Comment: But I want to display combobox in `cValor` column.

Comment: Ok, you must use `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmb.DataSource = dtDetalleRecordPorId;            
cmb.ValueMember = dtDetalleRecordPorId.Columns["idDetalleRecord"].ToString();
cmb.DisplayMember = dtDetalleRecordPorId.Columns["cValor"].ToString();
cmb.ReadOnly = false;
dtgRecord.Columns.Add(cmb);
```